# How to keep ViewModel and View sync'ed using validation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I have a `TextBox` who is bound to my model (I realize this should be in the VM, but this is the way it is currently). I have `ValidatesOnExcepion=true`, but when my property setter validates and throws an exception, then my model and view get out of sync (model remains old, view becomes new). I have even tried wrapping in a `try...finally` where the finally calls `OnPropertyChanged`. How do I keep both the View and Model set to the old value?

```
public Object MyProperty
{
    get{return _myProperty;}
    set
    {
        ThrowIfNotValid();
        _myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your property code pls. the short answer is: just bind to  string properties in conjunction with IDataErrorInfo.

Comment: @blindmeis I added a sample of what my property code essentially is. I have tried IDataErrorInfo, but that only deals with validating the value AFTER it has already changed, there is no built in way to roll back the change as far as I can see

Comment: Just a quick comment, I think this is what you are referring to in your first sentence but be aware that generally it's not best practice to bind your model directly to the view but rather have the viewmodel create the properties you need for the view.

Answer (score 0):

The updatesourcetrigger may work,

```
   <TextBox Text={Binding YourModel.PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a blog post](http://justin-pihony.blogspot.com/2013/05/validation-for-mvvm-properties-that.html) to elaborate on the pain that this has become, but I ended up going with a hybrid of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054510/wpf-text-box-not-updated-from-view-model).

I am using the above answer, but then had to create an interface similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the user since the above answer wipes away any validation errors